# Async all the way down?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

Trying to understand the new async/await pattern, I have one question which I can't find an answer to, namely if I should decorate my methods with async, if I intend to call those methods from other async functions, or just return `Task`s where appropriate?

In other words, which of these classes A, B or C is best, and why?

```
class A<T>
{
      public async Task<T> foo1() //Should be consumed
      {
          return await foo2();
      }

      public async Task<T> foo2() //Could be consumed
      {
          return await foo3();
      }

      private async Task<T> foo3() //Private
      {
          return await Task.Run(...);
      }
}

class B<T>
{
      public async Task<T> foo1() //Should be consumed
      {
          return await foo2();
      }

      public async Task<T> foo2() //Could be consumed
      {
          return await foo3();
      }

      private Task<T> foo3() //Private
      {
          return Task.Run(...);
      }
}

class C<T>
{
      public async Task<T> foo1() //Should be consumed
      {
          return await foo2();
      }

      public Task<T> foo2() //Could be consumed
      {
          return foo3();
      }

      private Task<T> foo3() //Private
      {
          return Task.Run(...);
      }
}
```

It seems redundant to overdecorate methods so I naturally lean toward `C`, but at the same time it feels somewhat awkward to work with `Task<T>` unless you use the `await` keyword.

Comment: BTW, the phrase "async all the way down" is usually meaning that you [shouldn't block on async code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx). This code - even if you don't use the `async` keyword - is still fully asynchronous. (As a side note, it seems to me that I first heard Lucian Wischik use the phrase, but right now I can't find a usage before Stephen Toub's blog entry).

Comment: This is exactly why I wish the async keyword requirement hadn't been added. I understand the 'might break existing code somewhere' but it leads to questions/confusion like this, compared to being able to opt-in to another compiler rewrite with yield return :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both versions work effectively the same, the only difference is that when you use `await` here, you get some performance penalty (because the state machine must be set up and a continuation will most likely be used).

So, it comes down to a tradeoff: Do you want your methods to be somewhat more efficient at the cost of being slightly less readable? Or are you willing to sacrifice performance for readability?

Usually, I would advise you to go for readability first and only focus on performance if profiling tells you it's worth it. But in this case, I think the increase in readability is small, so I would probably not use `await`.

Also note that your class `C` still doesn't go far enough: `foo1()` also doesn't need `await`.

Comment: +1. Though I would say more strongly that they should all *not* be `async`. IMO, this isn't less readable ... that is, **if** the reader understands that it is the *return type* of a method that is awaitable, not the *method itself*.

Answer (score 3):

The `async` in the signature is there to allow the compiler to create the state-machine rewriting of the contained code that is necessary to implement the `await` semantics in the general case.

Your example is exactly the special case where you do not need that rewriting: The asynchronous operation is the last thing happening within a method. That kind of method is already possible and valid in `.NET4.0`. This compatibility might be one reason to avoid `async` when you do not need it.