# Inside a loop,does each async call get chained to the returned task using task's continuewith?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

The best practice is to collect all the `async` calls in a collection inside the loop and do `Task.WhenAll()`. Yet, want to understand what happens when an `await` is encountered inside the loop, what would the returned `Task` contain? what about further `async` calls? Will it create new tasks and add them to the already returned `Task` sequentially?

As per the code below

```
private void CallLoopAsync()
{
   var loopReturnedTask = LoopAsync();
}

private async Task LoopAsync()
{
    int count = 0;
    while(count < 5)
    {
       await SomeNetworkCallAsync();
       count++;
    }
}
```

The steps I assumed are

1. `LoopAsync` gets called
2. `count` is set to zero, code enters while loop, condition is checked
3. `SomeNetworkCallAsync` is called,and the returned task is awaited
4. New task/awaitable is created
5. New task is returned to `CallLoopAsync`()

Now, provided there is enough time for the process to live, How / In what way, will the next code lines like `count++` and further `SomeNetworkCallAsync` be executed?

Update - Based on [Jon Hanna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400547/jon-hanna) and [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary):

> So there is one Task and the implementation of that Task will involve
>   5 calls to NetworkCallAsync, but the use of a state-machine means
>   those tasks need not be explicitly chained for this to work. This, for
>   example, allows it to decide whether to break the looping or not based
>   on the result of a task, and so on.

Though they are not chained, each call will wait for the previous call to complete as we have used `await` (in state m/c, `awaiter.GetResult();`). It behaves as if five consecutive calls have been made and they are executed one after the another (only *after* the previous call gets *completed*). If this is true, we have to be bit more careful in how we are composing the async calls.For ex:

Instead of writing

```
private async Task SomeWorkAsync()
{
   await SomeIndependentNetworkCall();// 2 sec to complete

   var result1 = await GetDataFromNetworkCallAsync(); // 2 sec to complete
   await PostDataToNetworkAsync(result1); // 2 sec to complete
}
```

It should be written

```
private Task[] RefactoredSomeWorkAsync()
{
    var task1 =  SomeIndependentNetworkCall();// 2 sec to complete

    var task2 = GetDataFromNetworkCallAsync()
    .ContinueWith(result1 => PostDataToNetworkAsync(result1)).Unwrap();// 4 sec to complete

    return new[] { task1, task2 };
}
```

So that we can say `RefactoredSomeWorkAsync` is faster by 2 seconds, because of the possibility of *parallelism*

```
private async Task CallRefactoredSomeWorkAsync()
{
   await Task.WhenAll(RefactoredSomeWorkAsync());//Faster, 4 sec 
   await SomeWorkAsync(); // Slower, 6 sec
}
```

Is this correct? - Yes. Along with "*async all the way*", "*Accumulate tasks all the way*" is good practice. Similar discussion is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21072505/1661861)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To produce code similar to what `async` and `await` do, if those keywords didn't exist, would require code a bit like:

```
private struct LoopAsyncStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine
{
  public int _state;
  public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder _builder;
  public TestAsync _this;
  public int _count;
  private TaskAwaiter _awaiter;
  void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
  {
    try
    {
      if (_state != 0)
      {
        _count = 0;
        goto afterSetup;
      }
      TaskAwaiter awaiter = _awaiter;
      _awaiter = default(TaskAwaiter);
      _state = -1;
    loopBack:
      awaiter.GetResult();
      awaiter = default(TaskAwaiter);
      _count++;
    afterSetup:
      if (_count < 5)
      {
        awaiter = _this.SomeNetworkCallAsync().GetAwaiter();
        if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
        {
          _state = 0;
          _awaiter = awaiter;
          _builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<TaskAwaiter, TestAsync.LoopAsyncStateMachine>(ref awaiter, ref this);
          return;
        }
        goto loopBack;
      }
      _state = -2;
      _builder.SetResult();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
      _state = -2;
      _builder.SetException(exception);
      return;
    }
  }
  [DebuggerHidden]
  void IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine param0)
  {
    _builder.SetStateMachine(param0);
  }
}

public Task LoopAsync()
{
  LoopAsyncStateMachine stateMachine = new LoopAsyncStateMachine();
  stateMachine._this = this;
  AsyncTaskMethodBuilder builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Create();
  stateMachine._builder = builder;
  stateMachine._state = -1;
  builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
  return builder.Task;
}
```

(The above is based on what happens when you use `async` and `await` except that the result of that uses names that cannot be valid C# class or field names, along with some extra attributes. If its `MoveNext()` reminds you of an `IEnumerator` that's not entirely irrelevant, the mechanism by which `await` and `async` produce an `IAsyncStateMachine` to implement a `Task` is similar in many ways to how `yield` produces an `IEnumerator<T>`).

The result is a single Task which comes from `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder` and makes use of `LoopAsyncStateMachine` (which is close to the hidden `struct` that the `async` produces). Its `MoveNext()` method is first called upon the task being started. It will then use an awaiter on `SomeNetworkCallAsync`. If it is already completed it moves on to the next stage (increment `count` and so on), otherwise it stores the awaiter in a field. On subsequent uses it will be called because the `SomeNetworkCallAsync()` task has returned, and it will get the result (which is void in this case, but could be a value if values were returned). It then attempts further loops and again returns when it is waiting on a task that is not yet completed.

When it finally reaches a `count` of 5 it calls `SetResult()` on the builder, which sets the result of the `Task` that `LoopAsync` had returned.

So there is one `Task` and the implementation of that `Task` will involve 5 calls to `NetworkCallAsync`, but the use of a state-machine means those tasks need not be explicitly chained for this to work. This, for example, allows it to decide whether to break the looping or not based on the result of a task, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

> When count is zero, new task will be created because of await and be returned

No. It will not. It will simply call the `async` method consequently, without storing or returning the result. The value in `loopReturnedTask` will store the `Task` of `LoopAsync`, not related to `SomeNetworkCallAsync`.

```
await SomeNetworkCallAsync(); // call, wait and forget the result
```

You may want to read the [MSDN article on async\await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Comment: I need to admit that while trying to explain it to the OP, I have become confused myself. That's why I decided to remove all other text.

Comment: My question is more on what would the task (of LoopAsync) contain particularly in the context of four more  SomeNetworkCallAsync calls as the control is yielded back to caller during the first loop.

Answer (score 1):

When an `async` method first yields at an `await`, it returns a `Task` (or `Task<T>`). This is *not* the task being observed by the `await`; it is a completely different task created by the `async` method. The `async` state machine controls the lifetime of that `Task`.

One way to think of it is to consider the returned `Task` as representing the method itself. The returned `Task` will only complete when the method completes. If the method returns a value, then that value is set as the result of the task. If the method throws an exception, then that exception is captured by the state machine and placed on that task.

So, there's no need for attaching continuations to the returned task. The returned task will not complete until the method is done.

> How / In what way, will the next code lines like count++ and further SomeNetworkCallAsync be executed?

I do explain this in my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) post. In summary, when a method `await`s, it captures a "current context" (`SynchronizationContext.Current` unless it is `null`, in which case it uses `TaskScheduler.Current`). When the `await` completes, it resumes executing its `async` method within that context.

That's what technically happens; but in the vast majority of cases, this simply means:

- If an `async` method starts on a UI thread, then it will resume on that same UI thread.
- If an `async` method starts within an ASP.NET request context, then it will resume with that same request context (not necessarily on the same thread, though).
- Otherwise, the `async` method resumes on a thread pool thread.