# Multithreading in C# and update tables

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to multithreading in C#. This is what I am trying to do.
I have a sql server table

```
create table dbo.temp(ID smallint not null, textfilename varchar(100) not null,isDone bit not null )

INSERT INTO dbo.temp(1,'textfile1.txt',0)
INSERT INTO dbo.temp(2,'textfile2.txt',0)
INSERT INTO dbo.temp(3,'textfile3.txt',0)
INSERT INTO dbo.temp(4,'textfile4.txt',0)
```

I have a c# program that Uses the contents of this textfile and updates other database tables 
and sets isdone=1. 
I know how to do this singlethread.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       public string filename = "";
        try
        {
         string query = "SELECT ID,textfilename FROM [somedatabase].[dbo].[temp] WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE isdone = 0 ORDER BY ID;";
         using (SqlConnection Conn= new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlConnStr"].ConnectionString))
         {
            Conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Conn))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        fileid = reader.GetInt16(0).ToString();
                        filename = reader.GetString(1);
                        StartProcessingFiles(filename);

                    }
                }
           }
         }
     }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw e;

        }
}
public static void StartProcessingFiles(string filename)
{
  //some business rules here

  //after processing them
  //Update [somedatabase].[dbo].[temp]  SET isdone=1 where filename=filename
}
}
```

How can I convert this to multithread say 3 files at a time

Comment: It is unlikely that this needs to be multithreaded.

Comment: How do you propose to stop the threads from processing the same entries?

Comment: well, in the SQL query i check if isdone=1 or 0

Comment: In which case you'd need to lock each row in the table as you process it until you've set `isdone = 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multithreading is for logic which is CPU-bound. Your database updates are not likely to be bound by the application server's CPU. So instead you might want to consider using `async`.

To do this, first break down your logic. Define a separate method to retrieve the file names:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFileNames()
{
     string query = "SELECT ID,textfilename FROM [somedatabase].[dbo].[temp] WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE isdone = 0 ORDER BY ID;";
     using (SqlConnection Conn= new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
        Conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Conn))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var filename = reader.GetString(1);
                    yield return filename;
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Then write code to process the list at the same time, asynchronously:

```
public async Task ProcessFiles()
{
    var files = GetFileNames();
    var tasks = files.Select( fileName => ProcessFile(fileName) );
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

For this to work, `ProcessFile` must be async too:

```
public async Task ProcessFile(string fileName)
{
     string query = "Update [somedatabase].[dbo].[temp]  SET isdone=1 where filename=@fileName";
     using (SqlConnection Conn= new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
        Conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileName", fileName);
            await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
       }
    }
}
```

Since the method uses `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`, it can return control to the caller and allow the next task to proceed (see [How do yield and await implement flow of control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287737/how-do-yield-and-await-implement-flow-of-control-in-net)). The tasks are all synchronized when you call `WhenAll`.

Comment: [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). Async methods like `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` utilize O/S threads and callbacks to avoid creating application threads. An additional thread is not necessary when the operation is not CPU-bound.

Answer (score 0):

To process multiple files at the same time I think you could replace

```cs
StartProcessingFiles(filename);
```

with

```cs
Task.Run(() => StartProcessingFiles(filename));
```

But then you have no guarantees about order in with the files are processed and database is updated.