# Using yield return to describe an iterator

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator, yield-return

I would really appreciate if someone checked out my thoughts on this topic and corrected them where they are wrong. I hope that this type of "please check my thoughts" doesn't go too much against the rules of the site, and my question is more of an attempt at an answer on how a certain topic works from someone who doesn't really understand the topic. Hopefully it could be valuable/insightful to someone who is a beginner like me and might want to see a high-level but very basic description of what's going on.

Here's my approach to understanding the topic of `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerator` and yield return.

The way `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` interact is quite clear and natural - we have two objects, one that holds the collection, one that has the cursor.

For the moment, let's ignore the connection between yield return and the two interfaces, and just consider the following concept/problem - suppose we have code that has an expression/computation of some integer on each line, and we would like to create a function `f` that executes and returns these integers in sequence, i.e. the first time we call `f()` it will return the integer that is computed on the first line, the second time we call it it will return the second integer, etc. The natural way to do this is to create some sort of helper class/object that will contain the mentioned code, but in addition to that it will also store the position of where we are in the code. Using `goto` this can be done. To achieve this, we designate a keyword of yield return to do this - the compiler recognizes that if we have some sort of block of code with yield returns inside, it will create a helper/controller class for it.  Notice that how this helper class acts on the block of code is already very similar to how an `IEnumerator` acts on `IEnumerable` - it stores "where" we are in some sense.

Next we will use this concept and define it so that it agrees with the existing functionality of `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerable` interfaces. The basic functionality that we will be aiming for is that of `foreach` - when used with an object that implements the `IEnumerable` interface, it returns the cursor implemented in `IEnumerator` via `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` and then uses methods of `MoveNext` and `current` to move along the collection and returns the object pointed to respectively.

So the first way we could use the concept is to only define the `GetEnumerator` - we simply put the block of code that we want to be executed sequentially in the body of `GetEnumerator`. For this to work, the compiler recognizes that if the body of the `GetEnumerator` contains `yield return`, it will create a helper object (and it will return this object to the call of `GetEnumerator` in the end), and this helper class will also implement the methods `MoveNext` and `Current` as "execute the next line, and save to `_current` (some field of the helper class) and "return `_current`" respectively. Essentially, `GetEnumerator` will return the helper object mentioned two paragraphs above, and in addition the compiler will create the needed `MoveNext` and `Current` methods in this helper object, so that they move along the block of code, return the value, respectively.

The other way we could use the concept is to directly "define" the collection and go through it. So this time, we're not just returning an `IEnumerator` / helper class, instead we're returning an `IEnumerable`. But for our purposes, we're really just interested in being able to use this object with `foreach`. So one way we can do this is to just do almost the same thing as above - we implement the helper object as an `IEnumerable` as well as `IEnumerator` - so we can return it as an `IEnumerable` in some `foreach` statement, and we implement the `GetEnumerator` to just return `this`. So the effect is very similar to the above.

Does the above make sense? One thing that I'm not clear on is whether for example `foreach` could somehow be used with `IEnumerator` directly - i.e. whether we could do `(foreach element in Enumerator())` where `Enumerator()` is a function that returns `IEnumerator` only, and not `IEnumerable`. It doesn't make sense, but I'm not sure whether the compiler can't figure these things out - especially since it's capable of determing to do such drastically different things if it sees `yield return` in the body, it then creates a helper object etc, like I've mentioned, so I'm not sure just how much other syntactic sugar there could be besides this.

Comment: I read this entire wall of text twice and I still do not understand this question at all. Try to start a sentence with "I want to...." or "I want the code to...." I also suggest *a lot* fewer words and more code. See [ask].

Comment: @JohnWu Thanks a lot for the comment, I'll delete the question and rewrite it sometime in a more coherent way. I don't really pose a precise question in the post - it's mostly just my own vague explanation of how yield/IEnumerate/IEnumerable work and interact, and why they interact the way they do. It's confusing for me, because I don't really have a precise question, and my code works fine, I'm just not completely confident why. The best description of the question would be something like "Is my intuition about why yield return works the way it works right?"

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287737/how-do-yield-and-await-implement-flow-of-control-in-net).