# In C# an async task waits to finish another async task before it executes

Tags: c#, async-await

I have this test methods,

```
private async Task<int> TestOnly()
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"asyncTest.txt"))
    {
        sw.WriteLine($"2 Written TestOnly().");
    }

    return 100;
}

private async Task TestAgain()
{
    await Task.Delay(0);
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"syncTest.txt"))
    {
        sw.WriteLine($"1 Written here TestAgain().");
    }
}

Private async Task Refresh()
{
    await TestOnly();
    await TestAgain();
}
```

If I call the Refresh(), what I am expecting that in `syncTest.txt`, the text `1 Written here TestAgain().` will print first than `2 Written TestOnly().` because the `TestOnly()` method awaiting 10 seconds before it writes into the `asyncTest.txt`. But when I run, it waits for it. Why is that?

Comment: `await`, waits for it to complete

Comment: `Refresh()` on `await TestOnly();` will wait all 10 sec, then write "2 Written" then return 100 and THEN run `await TestAgain();`. Either if you `Task.Run(async () => await TestOnly());` (without `await` before `Task.Run`) - it wouldn't wait for completion.

Comment: The explanation about async/await really confuses me because I though it will not wait but move to the next code to execute.

Comment: If you want to await multiple tasks at once, there's also the static method [`Task.WaitAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=net-5.0) and its various overloads.

Comment: As far as program flow is concerned, `await` is very much as if the thread were blocked. It's *not* actually blocked; the thread is free to go off and do other things until the awaited task is complete. When the task is complete, a thread (maybe the same one, maybe a different one) resumes executing your program at the next instruction after the `await`.

Comment: What do you think `await` does?  You've described what would happen if the `await` wasn't even there.  If it didn't do *anything* people wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 3):

When you `await` a task, you cause execution of the current method to suspend until the task is completed. Don't await a task until you're ready to wait for it.

```
private async Task Refresh()
{
    var task1 = TestOnly();
    var task2 = TestAgain();
    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}
```

You can also accomplish the whole thing without `async` or `await`. If you can see why, I think it will help you understand what `await` does.

```
private Task Refresh()
{
    var task1 = TestOnly();
    var task2 = TestAgain();
    return Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
}
```

This may also help: [How do yield and await implement control of flow in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287737/how-do-yield-and-await-implement-flow-of-control-in-net)